# Run an AWS Glue Crawler using Flex execution

Tags: amazon-web-services

The AWS Glue jobs API [supports](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/introducing-aws-glue-flex-jobs-cost-savings-on-etl-workloads/) an additional parameter called `execution-class`, which lets you choose STANDARD or FLEX when running the job.

How do I trigger an existing Glue Crawler using the FLEX `execution-class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex execution is only available for Glue Jobs not in Crawlers. For a Glue Job you activate Flex execution as default for the specific job in the Job details tab.